# It return null value when i am trying to get user id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get a logged in user data like id, name, email etc. I have to compare this id with another table called adminpictures and then display this picture if any record found against this id.

here is my code for getting user id

```
$id = Auth::id();
        dd($id);
```

but it return null, i want logged in user id. How i can do that. 
I am new in laravel

Comment: Is your user logged in? Auth::user() will return a user object if user is logged in else it return null. so verify once that your user is logged in

Comment: yes user is already loggedin

Comment: What is output of dd(Auth::user()); for your case ?

Comment: null......................

Comment: if `dd(Auth::user());` returns `null` which means the user doesnt have an active session. Check if your session driver is `array`. if so change it to file and try loggin in

Comment: check your `.env` file for a variable called `SESSION_DRIVER` and check if thats properly mapped to `driver` variable in `config/session.php`

Comment: its like this on .env file SESSION_DRIVER=file

Comment: please help me....

Comment: are you sending a `CORS` request? check if your request is having cookie called `laravel_session`.

Comment: how i can check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116335/discussion-between-cerlin-boss-and-muhammad-arslan).

Comment: Also please verify if your session directory ie storage/framework/session/ is writable if not then make it writable

Comment: @MuhammadArslan any luck?

Comment: if you are using latest version of laravel then you need to specify "WEB Middleware" in either route group or in route service provider this will run your auth session

Comment: i already add it in my routes

Comment: i am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1):

you can use sentinel middleware  for this.write this code in your controller if you are using default User model as your model for table in database.this code will work

```
use Sentinel;
$user = Sentinel::getUser();
dd($user);
```

this will print the user logged in
refer more on sentinel here
https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
        dd($id);
```

Comment: now i have this error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" this error occur now

Comment: i have a one user and user is logged in

Comment: logout and login again

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835886/laravel-authuser-id-tying-to-get-a-property-of-a-non-object

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo within your code, it should be

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
```

and not

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

You can check user is logged in or not simply using

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
}
```

Comment: now i have this error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You need to first check user exists or not.

Comment: how i can do that? i don't know about it

Comment: this check do nothing for me                                                                                         public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            // The user is logged in...
            $id = Auth::user()->id;
//            dd($id);
            return view('admin.index', compact('id'));
        }
    }

Comment: This seems to be work if you've properly managed to logged in user

Comment: cut paste return view code in this if condition and now it return blank page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116334/discussion-between-muhammad-arslan-and-uchiha).