# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object. i am trying to make automatic notification in my app.blade.php

Tags: php, authentication

```
<?php
  $order_utama = \App\Order::where('User_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('Status_Order', 0)->first();
 $notif = \App\Order_Detail::where('Order_id', $order_utama->id)->count();
?>
```

Comment: `Auth::user()` isn't returning an object.

Comment: What does `var_dump(Auth::user());` show?

Comment: That, or `$order_utama` is null because it couldn't find any matching orders.

Comment: Or maybe `$order_utama` isn't an object. Which line is getting the error?

Comment: this line:
 $order_utama = \App\Order::where('User_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('Status_Order', 0)->first();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Auth::user()->id looks like it is returning null:

A question like this has been answered before so I would really encourage you to go check it out here: [Laravel: Auth::user()->id trying to get a property of a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835886/laravel-authuser-id-trying-to-get-a-property-of-a-non-object)

Im wondering if you are instantiating your `Auth` class at the top of your file:

```
use Auth;
```