# Laravel 9 - How to get my session id in a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am creating a shop.

Situation : I am a logged user, and I would like to post an article I would like to sale. There is an image, name, description etc... for now everything is ok !

This is my shop database called boutiques in french :

[image]

I created a file upload for the image :

```
    public function CreateArticleAction(Request $request) {

    $requestData = $request->all();
    $fileName = time().$request->file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('img')->storeAs('boutique-storage', $fileName);
    $requestData["img"] = 'public/img/'.$path;
    dd($requestData);
    Boutique::create($requestData);
    return redirect('boutique')->with('flash_message', 'Article Addedd!');
}
```

And a model :

```
class Boutique extends Model
```

{

```
protected $fillable  = [
    "iduser",
    "idproduit",
    "nom",
    "description",
    "prix",
    "img",
    "quantité",
];
use HasFactory;
```

}

As you can see I can get everything I put on my inputs but I don't know how to get my session id back to post it on the database with my article !

[image]

EXAMPLE :

Caroline (idsession : 1) posted this ..... : article's information

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Are you mean user-id

Comment: `idsession` meaning the `user_id`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Auth::user()->id trying to get a property of a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835886/laravel-authuser-id-trying-to-get-a-property-of-a-non-object)

Comment: Have you tried `auth()->id()` to get authenticated user's id?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean :)

But how to post it on my code ?

Comment: `$request->session()->getId()` get the session ID. but not the user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have tried what is written on the doc

```
$id = Auth::user()->getId();

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user
```

Comment: or just auth()->id();

Comment: This works too Auth::id()